# Didselect Method of table will not call for another row until one row action will not perform completely

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

give me  suggestion  which is related to table view selection action.

I have a view in which  a table  with 2 section having 2 and 3 rows.When first section 2nd row select then a picker view comes for selecting a value. similarly 2nd section each row having its picker view for selecting values.So when  i am selecting a row the a picker view comes i want to make other rows didselect method will not call for  rows meanwhile  a picker view is showing on view and after selecting a value and done button pressed again user can select a row and picker view comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath`  to return **nil** or the **NSIndexPath**.  Like this :

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([myPickerView isHidden]) return indexPath;
    return nil;
}
```